# How do i remove a specific pattern from a specific lines using bash

Tags: text-processing, sed, latex

I want to remove a pattern `\textcolor{red}{` and replace `}}` by `}` from list of specific lines using bash
Let say i have a file

cat A.txt

```
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{5}\textcolor{red}{“Ahut isi inut chili kerik abang chili rik damlo. Alangli chili kerik ahut penang achili ke tovar akungsi klolo, lapen la aphan dongpon long-lo lapen nampi avo atum vangsi chongthok-et-lo.}}{\jverse{5}\textcolor{red}{“A sower went out to sow his seed; and as he sowed, some fell on the path and was trampled on, and the birds of the air ate it up.}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{6}\textcolor{red}{Lapen akaprek achili ke longpak athak klolo, lapen lake kechingjok pen mamat chekedulo, pima hadak longle kecham avedet-lo.}}{\jverse{6}\textcolor{red}{Some fell on the rock; and as it grew up, it withered for lack of moisture. }}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{7}\textcolor{red}{Akaprek achili ke ingsu kethe arong ajosi klolo, lapen ingsu kethe arong la pen the rap-rapsi la aphan petthip-lo.}}{\jverse{7}\textcolor{red}{Some fell among thorns, and the thorns grew with it and choked it.}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{8}\textcolor{red}{Jisu halatum aphan thak-lo, “Arnam Arat akepatu alam kechiniji, lake nangtum aphan nangpitang-lo, bonta akaprek atum aphan ke lamlir pensi thanlo. Lasi latum thek longbom setta thek longledetji lapen arjubom setta chini nedetji.” }}{\jverse{8}\textcolor{red}{He said, “To you it has been given to know the secrets of the kingdom of God; but to others I speak in parables, so that‘looking they may not perceive, and listening they may not understand.’}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{9}\textcolor{red}{“Bonta Lamlir athe lahelo: Chili ke Arnam alamlo.}}{\jverse{9}\textcolor{red}{“Now the parable is this: The seed is the word of God.}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{10}\textcolor{red}{Tovar akung keklo achili ke karjulong atumlo; latum kroikredetsi kejok kelongledetji aphan Diabol vangsi halatum aning arlo pen alam pondet-lo.}}{\jverse{10}\textcolor{red}{The ones on the path are those who have heard; then the devil comes and takes away the word from their hearts, so that they may not believe and be saved.}}
```

Let say i have a list of lines to remove the pattern is line 1 and line 3
so my final output after removing and replacing the pattern will be

```
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{5}“Ahut isi inut chili kerik abang chili rik damlo. Alangli chili kerik ahut penang achili ke tovar akungsi klolo, lapen la aphan dongpon long-lo lapen nampi avo atum vangsi chongthok-et-lo.}{\jverse{5}“A sower went out to sow his seed; and as he sowed, some fell on the path and was trampled on, and the birds of the air ate it up.}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{6}\textcolor{red}{Lapen akaprek achili ke longpak athak klolo, lapen lake kechingjok pen mamat chekedulo, pima hadak longle kecham avedet-lo.}}{\jverse{6}\textcolor{red}{Some fell on the rock; and as it grew up, it withered for lack of moisture. }}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{7}Akaprek achili ke ingsu kethe arong ajosi klolo, lapen ingsu kethe arong la pen the rap-rapsi la aphan petthip-lo.}{\jverse{7}Some fell among thorns, and the thorns grew with it and choked it.}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{8}\textcolor{red}{Jisu halatum aphan thak-lo, “Arnam Arat akepatu alam kechiniji, lake nangtum aphan nangpitang-lo, bonta akaprek atum aphan ke lamlir pensi thanlo. Lasi latum thek longbom setta thek longledetji lapen arjubom setta chini nedetji.” }}{\jverse{8}\textcolor{red}{He said, “To you it has been given to know the secrets of the kingdom of God; but to others I speak in parables, so that‘looking they may not perceive, and listening they may not understand.’}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{9}\textcolor{red}{“Bonta Lamlir athe lahelo: Chili ke Arnam alamlo.}}{\jverse{9}\textcolor{red}{“Now the parable is this: The seed is the word of God.}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{10}\textcolor{red}{Tovar akung keklo achili ke karjulong atumlo; latum kroikredetsi kejok kelongledetji aphan Diabol vangsi halatum aning arlo pen alam pondet-lo.}}{\jverse{10}\textcolor{red}{The ones on the path are those who have heard; then the devil comes and takes away the word from their hearts, so that they may not believe and be saved.}}
```

I tried with this command but it is not working

```
VAR=\\texcolor{red}{
sed -i "1s/$VAR//;3s/$VAR//" A.txt
```

I know how to delete a pattern from all the lines but i don't know for specific line.

Comment: Did you actually test your regex on all the lines? `\t` is special in sed (representing a tab character) so needs to be escaped again i.e. `VAR=\\\\textcolor{red}{`

Answer (score 1):

Like @steeldriver said, you need to use 4 back slashes, so they are escaped properly, like so: `VAR="\\\\textcolor{red}{"`. Your `sed` command should work without any changes. Also, you misspelled 'textcolor'.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with below awk command and it worked fine

```
awk 'NR==1||3{gsub(/\\textcolor{red}/,"",$0);print $0}' filename
```

output

```
\ParallelLText{\jverse{5}{“Ahut isi inut chili kerik abang chili rik damlo. Alangli chili kerik ahut penang achili ke tovar akungsi klolo, lapen la aphan dongpon long-lo lapen nampi avo atum vangsi chongthok-et-lo.}}{\jverse{5}{“A sower went out to sow his seed; and as he sowed, some fell on the path and was trampled on, and the birds of the air ate it up.}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{6}{Lapen akaprek achili ke longpak athak klolo, lapen lake kechingjok pen mamat chekedulo, pima hadak longle kecham avedet-lo.}}{\jverse{6}{Some fell on the rock; and as it grew up, it withered for lack of moisture. }}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{7}{Akaprek achili ke ingsu kethe arong ajosi klolo, lapen ingsu kethe arong la pen the rap-rapsi la aphan petthip-lo.}}{\jverse{7}{Some fell among thorns, and the thorns grew with it and choked it.}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{8}{Jisu halatum aphan thak-lo, “Arnam Arat akepatu alam kechiniji, lake nangtum aphan nangpitang-lo, bonta akaprek atum aphan ke lamlir pensi thanlo. Lasi latum thek longbom setta thek longledetji lapen arjubom setta chini nedetji.” }}{\jverse{8}{He said, “To you it has been given to know the secrets of the kingdom of God; but to others I speak in parables, so that‘looking they may not perceive, and listening they may not understand.’}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{9}{“Bonta Lamlir athe lahelo: Chili ke Arnam alamlo.}}{\jverse{9}{“Now the parable is this: The seed is the word of God.}}
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{10}{Tovar akung keklo achili ke karjulong atumlo; latum kroikredetsi kejok kelongledetji aphan Diabol vangsi halatum aning arlo pen alam pondet-lo.}}{\jverse{10}{The ones on the path are those who have heard; then the devil comes and takes away the word from their hearts, so that they may not believe and be saved.}}
```

praveen@praveen:~$

Comment: Final output is not correct @Praveen Kumar BS

Comment: `NR==1||3` will always be true; you would need `NR==1||NR==3` I think